# Can't print data from the room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, dagger-hilt

Learning `Hilt` is giving me a hard time, so I've decided to ask you for help.

I have an, where I'd like to perform basic `cruds` on `room database`. I have inserted some data already, and now, I'd like to display it in console, but I can't manage to do it. It just doesn't print anything at all.

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface EmployeeDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM employees")
    fun getEmployees(): Flow<EmployeeModel>`
}
```

**repository interface**

```
interface EmployeeRepository {
    suspend fun getEmployees(): Flow<EmployeeModel>
}
```

**repository implementation**

```
class RepositoryImplementation @Inject constructor(
    private val employeeDAO: EmployeeDAO): EmployeeRepository {

    override suspend fun getEmployees(): Flow<EmployeeModel> {
        return employeeDAO.getEmployees()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class EmployeeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: dagger.Lazy<EmployeeRepository>
) : ViewModel() {


    suspend fun getEmployees() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.get().getEmployees().collect{
            println("TEST: ${it.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ManageEmployees : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentManageEmployeesBinding? = null
    private val mBinding get() = _binding!!
    private val mViewModel: EmployeeViewModel by activityViewModels()
    @Inject
    lateinit var repo: EmployeeRepository

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentManageEmployeesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = mBinding.root

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                mViewModel.getEmployees()
            }
        }
        return view
    }
```

**Repository module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindRepository(
        repositoryImplementation: RepositoryImplementation
    ): EmployeeRepository
}
```

**Database module**

```
    @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun createDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        EmployeeDatabase::class.java,
        "employee_database"
    ).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDAO(database: EmployeeDatabase): EmployeeDAO{
        return database.getDAO()
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error ? Could you please share the logs.

Comment: @KamalNayan there's no errors.

Comment: could you please share the code for injecting employeeDAO used here `RepositoryImplementation @Inject constructor(
    private val employeeDAO: EmployeeDAO)`

Comment: have you defined the provide dao like this `@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideYourDao(db: YourDatabase) = db.getEmployeeDAO()`

Comment: @KamalNayan I just updated the question. And I've done it slightly different. I'll try it once again with ur code.

Comment: you will have to define `getEmployeeDAO()` method in database like :  `@Database(
    entities = [ItemsYouAreStoringInDB::class], // Tell the database the entries will hold data of this type
    version = 1
)

abstract class YourDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getYourDao(): YourDAO
}`

Comment: @KamalNayan it is printing everything now. Thank you for help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I have posted this solution in answer. Kindly mark this answer as correct answer and upvote it, as it helped you and can help someone else in future.

Comment: @KamalNayan I have accepted it, but can't vote up yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you will have to define getEmployeeDAO() method in database like :**

```
 // Tell the database the entries will hold data of this type  
@Database(     entities = [ItemsYouAreStoringInDB::class],version = PUT_YOUR_DATABASE_VERSION )
 abstract class YourDatabase : RoomDatabase()
{
     abstract class YourDatabase : RoomDatabase() { 
         abstract fun getYourDao(): YourDAO 
    }
}
```

**then provide DAO like this :**

```
@Singleton 
@Provides
fun provideYourDao(db: YourDatabase) = db.getEmployeeDAO()
```